# Yii2 - ActiveDataProvider Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii, yii2

I am getting following error when I try to use ActiveDataProvider in order to display connected table (**hasOne** connection):

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
```

My model:

```
public function dataProvider()
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Currency::find()->with('country'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'allowed' => SORT_DESC,
                ]
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

**hasOne** connection:

```
public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Countries::className(), ['country_code' => 'country_code']);
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function actionManage()
    {
        return $this->render('manage', [
            'dataProvider' => Currency::find()->dataProvider(),
        ]);
    }
```

View:

```
Pjax::begin(
    ['linkSelector' => 'a:not(.linksWithTarget)']
);

    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'label'  => 'Country',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->country->country_name;
                },
            ],
        ],

    ]);

Pjax::end();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your relation `getCountry()` returned `null`. Always check if relation isset, simply replace `value` by: `$model->country ? $model->country->country_name : null`

Answer (score 0):

Dear sir you need to have relation name country first , if you set a relation in your database , GII can build it for you .
if not you can simple do it easily  by 2 find!( not recommended )

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'label'  => 'Country',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return   Country::findOne($model->country_id)->country_name;
                },
            ],
        ],

    ]);
```